# How to check against a DB Table in Mapforce?

Tags: sql, excel, database, string-comparison, map-force

The question is about mapping in Mapforce.

I have an Excel input file. I also have a table from Oracle DB.

What I want to do is the following:
Take **tournr** from Excel and compare it to **tournr** in Table from DB. When there is a match, take NR column from DB table.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my own. Need to use 'INSERT SQL WHERE/ORDER' from the menu where constant, DB's are etc. And you can do JOINs with a couple of SQL filters like this one if connected properly.

[SQL filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbbhh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the new **Join Component**. If you click out the **[SQL]** button on the top right of the component then you can join **non-SQL** sources.